# How to write a perl script to grab data out?

Tags: perl

I have a txt file, and it looks like:

```
Name: X1

Year:2010

Number:100

Status:OK


Name: X2

Year:2011

Number:200

Status:NO
```

How to write a perl script to read this txt file in and make the output look like:

```
Name Number  Status

X1   100     OK    
X2   200     NO
```

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Every Perl starter would be able to write this

Answer (score 3):

Try this book - the first couple of chapters will help you to write your script: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do